# Bluetooth Low Energy with Android NDK

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I am developing an app which connects to an [EEG board](https://shop.openbci.com/collections/frontpage/products/pre-order-ganglion-board?variant=13461804483) over BLE. 
My app is building on [Google BLE Gatt Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) and is used to receive EEG samples from the previously mentioned board. 
These samples are transmitted as 100 packets/s as this is the limit according to them, before major packet loss is to be expected.

After experiencing some packet loss (around 6%) on the tablet (Huawei Mediapad T3 10) we use for testing, I wanted to find the cause for this issue.
I removed every bit of code used to process the data and only left in the code to calculate and track the number of lost packets:

```
private static void updatePacketsCount(int packetID){
        // Update last packet ID and dropped packets
        totalPackets++;
        int packets_dropped;
        if (last_id == -1){
            last_id = packetID;
            return;
        }
         // ID loops every 101 packets
        if (packetID > last_id){
            packets_dropped = packetID - last_id - 1;
        } else{
            packets_dropped = packetID + 101 - last_id - 1;
        }
        last_id = packetID;
        if (packets_dropped > 0){
            if (packets_dropped==100)
                return;
            Log.e(TAG, "Warning: dropped " + packets_dropped + " packets.");
            lostPackets = lostPackets + packets_dropped;
        }
    }
```

After taking out the possible CPU intensive code I was still experiencing the same packet loss, so I tested 4 devices in total

**Redmi Note 3 (MTK) on Android 5.0.2 with Bluetooth v4.1:**

A/GanglionBluetoothLeService: Lost: 0 out of 64509 % of loss= 0.0

**Doogee X5max pro on Android 6.0 with Bluetooth v4.0**

E/GanglionBluetoothLeService: Lost: 3596 out of 63550 % of loss= 5.658536585365853

**Huawei Mediapad T3 10 on Android 7.0 with Bluetooth v4.0**

E/GanglionBluetoothLeService: Lost: 2689 out of 42640 % of loss= 6.306285178236398

**Teclast X98 Plus II on Android 5.1.1 with Bluetooth v4.0**

A/GanglionBluetoothLeService: Lost: 808 out of 65388 % of loss= 1.235700740196978

All of the devices were placed on a desk about 20cm next to the board.

Now to my actual question, is this rather a hardware or a software issue? It seems like the device with Bluetooth 4.1 performed as expected compared to the devices with 4.0?
Or could this be due to CPU latency/ weak performance? Someone suggested using the Android NDK to achieve better results, but I am wondering if that would even provide improvement over the official Google sample code.

**Edit:**
The eeg board is running the firmware https://github.com/OpenBCI/OpenBCI_Ganglion_Library 
sending the data looks like this:

```
void OpenBCI_Ganglion::sendCompressedPacket19() {
  radioBuffer[0] = ringBufferLevel + 100;
  for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    radioBuffer[i+1] = compression_ring[ringBufferLevel][i];
  }
  ringBufferLevel++;
  if (BLEconnected) {
    SimbleeBLE.send(radioBuffer, 20);
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the data? The Link Layer in BLE is reliable in a way that there can not be any packet losses. Of course a sending device may ignore to send a packet if the outgoing buffers are full. What is your connection interval? You should also use a BLE sniffer to see what's going on in the air. There is most likely no issues with the CPU speed and such.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by how I am sending the Data, the eeg board is running the firmware it came with

Comment: But if the issue was on the board, shouldnt there be at least some packet loss all the time? With one device having no packet loss at all and another significantly less, it looks like the issue is rather on the receiving end to me. How do I check the connection interval and can you recommend a BLE packet sniffer?

Comment: I experience the same type of problems with a SHT-W09 (Mediapad M5) with BT 4.2 and a SM-T280 (Samsung Galaxy Tab) with BT 4.0. Most devices just work fine, even very "near" configurations (SM-T230, SM-T280). I noticed that the problem occurs always when the callback come with more than 10 bytes of data. So it seems that there is a receive buffer overflow. But I can't find a ways to configure anything at this level. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: It seems like this is a problem of how the bluetooth stack is working, as in it isn't meant to handle 100+ packets per second because it doesn't work on a high priority interrupt basis. Please check here for more info http://openbci.com/index.php/forum/#/discussion/1425/ganglion-ble-dropped-packet-ids-with-android-library

Comment: Another anecdote from someone working on the same issue, it seems that on devices with a faster soc it works better, with devices equivalent to the Pixel 2 and Iphone 6s or better.